# Speed of sound in moving closed container

Tags: relative-motion

If I am standing in an airplane (air inside moving with the plane) with a someone talking to me while the plane is going 800k/hr. Would the the speed of the sound of the person talking to me go 800k/hr + the speed of sound relative to Earth or would the sound only the speed of sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Air rest speed determines how fast the sound Will propagate trough it.

Let's say the airplane is going at 3 times the speed of sound. That sound would be in one moment 4 times ahead of the sound that was made outside the plane at the very same time.